# Why is my if statement being entered when passed a null block?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to make a failsafe to guarantee a null block is never attempted to be executed. To do this, I use a custom property getter, which returns the block if it's not null, else it returns an empty block. **However!** The `if` statement is always entered! Then, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when it tries to return the block!

It looks like the block isn't defined, as it has a value of `0x0000000000000000`, and its `__FuncPtr` is `NULL`, so why is this `if` statement being entered?

[image: A screenshot of Xcode, showing an object called _pinPadCompletionBlock with a value of 0x0000000000000000, as the only conditional in an if statement, and the program counter on the next line. Below this is the inspector wherein __FuncPtr is NULL.]

My block is declared as:

```objective-c
@property (nonatomic, assign) void (^pinPadCompletionBlock)(bool);
```

Comment: Perhaps the block should be a typedef to make it more semantic and avoid other possible errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in how the property is declared. **Blocks cannot be declared as `assign`. Simply change your declaration to use `copy`, instead**:

```objective-c
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^pinPadCompletionBlock)(bool);
```

Additionally, if you look further than the `__FuncPtr`, you'll see that there are set values inside the block, meaning that **the block isn't actually null, despite the debugger readout**. So, the code is behaving properly in entering that statement, and I think you'll find that after changing `assign` to `copy`, the block's value will be something more obviously non-null when you get to the `if` statement..

Comment: Any type _can_ be used with an `assign` property, including a Block, but it won't be copied off the stack when it's assigned. Also, if the pointer to the Block is `nil` then whatever else you're seeing in the Block's fields is garbage that's being misinterpreted by the debugger. Nothing lives at 0x0; you can't have a valid object with that address.